# Show function names with dashes in sidebar with Sphinx and function directive

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm using Sphinx 7.2.5 with the [Furo](https://github.com/pradyunsg/furo/) theme and documenting functions that are not Python and therefore can have dashes in their names. The `function` directive generally works as desired except that functions with dashes in their names don't show up in the sidebar. I'd appreciate help either fixing this or approaching how to troubleshoot it! Maybe there's an escape character that can be used? Or maybe it's a bug somewhere, but I don't know enough about Sphinx to know where to look.

Here's an example:

```
.. function:: count-non-empty(nodeset)

  Returns the number of non-empty members of ``nodeset``.
```

You can see it rendered below https://docs.getodk.org/form-operators-functions/#count, note that `count-non-empty` is not in the right sidebar.

Code at https://github.com/getodk/docs/blob/master/docs/form-operators-functions.rst?plain=1#L353

Comment: Your documentation is using the Furo theme? The right sidebar is theme specific because not every theme has it. You should post this at the theme's issue tracker.

Comment: I've verified that the pydata theme has the same problem so I think it's deeper than themes.

Comment: My guess is the recent PyData and Furo themes share the right side bar for the most part. I don't know what the source of that element is but reporting on the issue tracker of one, or the other, theme is the surest way for the devs to address the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We discovered via the Furo theme's discussion board that this is because of Sphinx using the Python domain by default. Python does not allow `-` in identifiers, but adding `primary_domain = 'js'` to the Sphinx `conf.py` should allow these to work correctly.

Comment: Check the [more domains](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/domains/index.html#more-domains) section to see if something more adequate than `js` may apply to your case. Apparently the language in the OP is *XLSForms*, from their docs: *"XLSForm is a standard for designing forms in Excel."* so if a specific Sphinx domain for that language isn't available you either have to create one or get creative with the domains that are available.

Comment: The functions are XPath and the JS domain is a great fit for that. Turns out that we had it configured correctly some years back but lost it in a theme transition. 